Spring Boot Buildpacks fails to build - unlinkat /workspace/BOOT-INF: permission denied
I have a functioning spring-boot 3.3.3 service I'm trying to compile in native mode inside a podman container with the command:
mvnw clean package -Pnative spring-boot:build-image -Ddocker.publishRegistry.username=%username% -Ddocker.publishRegistry.password=%password% -Ddocker.publishRegistry.url=https://workharbour

The buildpack is pull and the compilation seems to be working. Sadly, the buildpack fails with a permission denied at the end:
[INFO]     [creator]        22.2s (9.3% of total time) in 1321 GCs | Peak RSS: 6.36GB | CPU load: 9.61
[INFO]     [creator]     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     [creator]     Produced artifacts:
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/it.pes.blab.anagrafiche.AnagraficheApplication (executable)
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/libawt.so (jdk_library)
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/libawt_headless.so (jdk_library)
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/libawt_xawt.so (jdk_library)
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/libfontmanager.so (jdk_library)
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/libfreetype.so (jdk_library)
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/libjava.so (jdk_library_shim)
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/libjavajpeg.so (jdk_library)
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/libjvm.so (jdk_library_shim)
[INFO]     [creator]      /layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/liblcms.so (jdk_library)
[INFO]     [creator]     ================================================================================
[INFO]     [creator]     Finished generating 'AnagraficheApplication' in 3m 57s.
[INFO]     [creator]       Removing bytecode
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to remove /workspace/BOOT-INF
[INFO]     [creator]     unlinkat /workspace/BOOT-INF: permission denied
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  05:58 min

I am using java 21, which the buildpack correctly detects ($BP_JVM_VERSION 21 reported on logs). It looks like the image is being built, but the cleanup phase is failing...How could I better debug the error?

I've not seen this before. The permissions for your application files are inherited from your local machine. So first thing I'd check would be the permissions inside your JAR file on the directory listed there. If it's anything but 755, look at why and change that. The buildpack wants to delete these files because the only thing it wants to end up in your final image is the binaries that were built. That's the clean up that's failing here.

as reported in the first received answer, the problem is probably related to podman version. Today I updated to Podman 5.2.5 (over podman desktop 1.13.3) and the issue is the same

I have had the same problem since i installed podman 5.1.2 on my machine. I also tried with podman 5.2.5 but the problem persisted. Today i tried with docker 27.3.1 and it worked, so i think that the problem is related to the latest versions of podman.

I tried 5.3.1, but i got same now...
I was used docker but changed to podman recently day.
I assume podman + bootBuildImage command is not stable now.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
